# Nested resource with Ember and Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a Rails app with User an Company. I'm currently trying to implement Ember just for the settings page.

So far, I have the following routes in Rails:
/account
/account/api-keys
/account/subscriptions
/account/team

Only thing is on some of those pages, /account for example, you can edit your User details and Company details.

Not too sure what is the best way to handle this with Ember. Should I have a route just for User properties and one for Company properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general you should have a route for every unique "screen" that you want to present to users.  So if a `User` and a `Company` should be displayed (or edited) separately, then yes, you should have a route for each.